# How to get the top 5 per enum of a model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Let's say I have a model named `post`, which has an `enum` named `post_type` which can either be
`admin`, `public` or `user`

```
#app/models/post.rb

class Post < ApplicationRecord
 enum post_type: [ :admin, :public, :user ]
end
```

How can I select 5 last created posts from each category?

I can't think of any other solution than this:

```
PER_GROUP = 5

admin_posts = Post.admin.order(created_at: :desc).limit(PER_GROUP)
user_posts = Post.user.order(created_at: :desc).limit(PER_GROUP)
public_posts = Post.public.order(created_at: :desc).limit(PER_GROUP)
```

Is there any way I could fetch all the rows in the required manner from just a single query to the database.

## STACK

```
RAILS : 6
PostgresSQL: 9.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Belayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7623856/belayer) i was able to come up with a solution.

```
PER_GROUP = 5

sub_query = Post.select('*', 'row_number() over (partition by "posts"."post_type" ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC ) rn').to_sql

@posts = Post.from("(#{sub_query}) inner_query")
             .where('inner_query.rn <= ?', PER_GROUP')
             .order(:post_type, created_at: :desc)
             .group_by(&:post_type)
```

Since i am only loading 5 records across just a few different types `group_by` will work just fine for me.

Comment: It is interesting to see the translated solution. I am just greatful I do not have to build one, especially if there were multiple levels of sub-selects. But glade I could offer assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to translate into RAILS, but it is straight forward Postgres query. You use the row_number window function in a sub-select then keep only rows with row_number less than or equal 5 on the outer select.

```
select *
  from (select post_txt
             , posted_type
             , row_number() over (partition by posted_type) rn
          from enum_table
       ) pt
 where rn <= 5 
 order by posted_type;
```

One thing to look out for is the sorting on an enum. Doing so gives results in order of the definition, not a "natural order" (alphanumeric in this case). See [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d82c999a3c6f1fd4589f833a6d2576f6).

Comment: Thanks @Belayer, i will try to translate this to `ActiveRecords`.